# No suitable method

Tags: java, arrays, list

I have this error of no suitable method and am unsure what it means, the error is in this line **vertices.set(v, new ArrayList());**

```
List<Vertex> vertices = new ArrayList<Vertex>();

public Vertex insertVertex(String n){
   Vertex v = new Vertex(n);
   vertices.set(v, new ArrayList<Edge>());    
   return n;
}
```

Comment: what is `vertices` in your code?

Comment: vertices = new ArrayList<Vertex>();

Comment: Do you know what a list is? What do you think `set` is supposed to do?

Comment: `ArrayList.set()` accepts `int` as a first parameter because it is an index where to set. You might need to use `Map<Vertex, List<Edge>>` instead

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList`'s `.set` method accepts index as first argument.

If you want to add your vertex to `vertices`, try this:

```
vertices.add(v);
```

If you want store a vertex along with it's adjacent edges, try use some Map:

```
Map<Vertex, List<Edge>> vertices = new HashMap<Vertex, List<Edge>>();

public Vertex insertVertex(String n){
   Vertex v = new Vertex(n);
   vertices.put(v, new ArrayList<Edge>());    
   return n;
}
```